# Matlab: determinant of a matrix of vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, determinants

I have a 2x2 matrix, each element of which is a 1x5 vector. something like this:

```
x = 1:5;
A = [ x  x.^2; x.^2 x];
```

Now I want to find the determinant, but this happens

```
B = det(A);
Error using det
Matrix must be square.
```

Now I can see why this happens, MATLAB sees A as a 2x10 matrix of doubles. I want to be able to treat x as an element, not a vector. What I'd like is `det(A) = x^2 - x^4`, then get `B = det(A)` as a 1x5 vector.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want a vectorized version of 'det'?

Comment: why can't you just compute `det(A) = x.^2 - x.^4`?

Comment: Because I was just demonstrating a simple example. The actual matrix I need to work with is 4x4 and has loads of bessel functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Matlab has symbolic facilities, they aren't great.  Instead, you really want to vectorize your operation.  This can be done in a loop, or you can use [`ARRAYFUN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) for the job.  It sounds like `ARRAYFUN` would probably be easier for your problem.

The `ARRAYFUN` approach:

```
x = 1:5;
detFunc = @(x) det([ x x^2 ; x^2 x ]);

xDet = arrayfun(detFunc, x)
```

Which produces:

```
>> xDet = arrayfun(detFunc, x)
xDet =
     0   -12   -72  -240  -600
```

For a more complex determinant, like your 4x4 case, I would create a separate M-file for the actual function (instead of an anonymous function as I did above), and pass it to `ARRAYFUN` using a function handle:

```
xDet = arrayfun(@mFileFunc, x);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the anonymous function approach because I couldn't get it to work otherwise. Kept spitting errors about "Not enough inputs" or something.

Answer (score 1):

Well mathematically a [Determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is only defined for a square matrix.  So unless you can provide a square matrix you're not going to be able to use the determinant.

*Note* I know wikipedia isn't the end all resource.  I'm simply providing it as I can't readily provide a print out from my college calculus book.

Update: Possible solution?

```
x = zeros(2,2,5);
x(1,1,:) = 1:5;
x(1,2,:) = 5:-1:1;
x(2,1,:) = 5:-1:1;
x(2,2,:) = 1:5;

for(n=1:5)
    B(n) = det(x(:,:,n));
end
```

Would something like that work, or are you looking to account for each vector at the same time?  This method treats each 'layer' as it's own, but I have a sneaky suspiscion that you're wanting to get a single value as a result.

Comment: The thing is, if you treat x symbolically then I do have a square matrix. What I need to figure out is how to calculate the determinant symbolically and then substitute a vector for x.

Comment: Just a toss up off the top of my head here as a possible soultion.  Updated the answer with it.

Comment: Although I didn't end up using this solution, it was helpful for something else I was doing with the determinant so I'm going to upvote it.

Comment: Glad I could help a little bit at least =P